# Envío de mensaje a whatsapp con php

Tags: php, whatsapp

necesito enviar a whatsapp un mensaje en base a un pedido,esta orden puede contener varios productos para diferentes empresas por lo que necesito armar una cadena con los productos solicitados para cada empresa,por ejemplo se solicita una hamburguesa y un arroz cantonés del comercio 1 y un sushi del comercio 2 así que lo que ocupo es enviar un mensaje al comercio 1 diciendo el usuario tal solicita una hamburguesa y un arroz cantonés y otro mensaje al comercio 2 diciendo que el usuario tal solicita un sushi,tengo un código para agrupar categorías dentro de un acordeón, este es el código:

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$usuario = "";
if (isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {
  $usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
  
}

include("conexion.php");
$sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $usuario);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

foreach ($sth as $row ) { 

   $rol = $row["rol"];
   $usuario_id = $row["id"];
   
   $nombre = $row["nombre"];
   $apellidos = $row["apellidos"];

}

}

$nombre_usuario = $nombre." ".$apellidos;

$comerciosarr = array();
$whatssarr = array();
$sth = $con->prepare("SELECT *  FROM carrito WHERE id_usuario =? ");
$sth->bindParam(1, $usuario_id);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

foreach ($sth as $row ) 
 {
    
  $comerciosarr[] = $row["nombre_empresa"];
  $whatssarr[] = $row["whatss"];   
    
 }

}
$comerciosarr = array_unique($comerciosarr);
$whatssarr = array_unique($whatssarr);

#var_dump($whatssarr);
#exit();
$texto = "";

if(!empty($comerciosarr)){
  
  
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($comerciosarr); $i++) 
        {
            if(!empty($comerciosarr[$i]))
            {
              $comercio = $comerciosarr[$i];
              $whatss = $whatssarr[$i];

                $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrito WHERE nombre_empresa = ? AND id_usuario = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $comercio);
$sth->bindParam(2, $usuario_id);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
$arreglo = array();
foreach ($sth as $row ) 
{ 
  array_push($arreglo,$row["articulo"]);
  $codigo = $row["codigo"];
  
  # CONSULTA A LA TABLA DETALLES CARRITO

    $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM detalles_carrito WHERE codigo = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $codigo);
#$sth->bindParam(2, $usuario_id);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) 
{
  $extras = array();

foreach ($sth as $row ) 
{ 
  array_push($extras,$row["descripcion"]);
}

}



  # CONSULTA A LA TABLA DETALLES CARRITO
}


#var_dump($arreglo);
$arreglo = implode(",", $arreglo);
$extras = implode(",", $extras);

$texto = "Saludos ".$comercio." El usuario " .$nombre_usuario. " ha solicitado los siguientes productos ".$arreglo." con las siguientes extras: ".$extras;
print_r($texto);

}
            
            }
            header('refresh:5;url=https://wa.me/'.$whatss.'/?text='.$texto);
          }
        }

?>
```

El problema es que solo envía un mensaje y en este caso son dos.Cualquier ayuda la agradeceré montones.Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Este código está mal planteado desde el principio. No tienes por qué seleccionar siempre TOOODOS los menús. Lo lógico es que selecciones SÓLO el menú de ese usuario para ESA fecha / hora, o los menús de ESE usuario aún no completados o algo así. Dicho eso, depura tu código. Dinos si los `var_dump` que tienes muestran algo, aunque sea `NULL`. Dinos si verificaste que realmente existen datos con esos criterios en la BD. Por último, el Manual de PHP te dice con claridad meridiana que **no deberías confiar en `rowCount()` para consultas del tipo `SELECT`**, cosa que haces aquí impunemente.

Comment: Buen día, ya edité el código,tal y como mencionas selecciono solo los comercios que se han agregado al carrito, no todos,ahora solo me envía un mensaje y no sé porqué si son dos en este caso. @A.Cedano

Comment: Y sobre lo de rowCount() cuál sería la mejor forma de realizar esta consulta? @A.Cedano

Comment: Hola @Samael. No he revisado muy en detalle el código, pero a simple vista tu problema es el `refresh`. Para enviar el 1er mensaje es necesario ir/navegar a dicha dirección lo que implica dejar de ejecutar el resto de las instrucciones. Deberías abrir nuevas ventanas o pestañas con cada nueva dirección a WhatsApp utilizando código Javascript. [Así por ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Si los mensajes se van a enviar desde PHP, usando una API para WhatsApp o algo por el estilo, no veo qué sentido tienen los `refresh`, como ya te señala @Marcos en su comentario. Y si necesitas alguna respuesta en el cliente (Javascript / HTML), entonces considera usar Ajax. En cuanto a lo de `rowCount()`, la mejor manera de contar datos es con un `SELECT COUNT(*)` o bien puedes verificar los datos mismos después de hacer `fetch`: si están vacíos es que esa consulta no arrojó filas.

Comment: @A.Cedano el refresh es para que se haga la redirección después del tiempo especificado, en mi caso puse 5 segundos,y ya uso un API de whatsapp, lo que se llama clic para chatear: `<a class="btn btn-info" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://wa.me/<?= $whatss; ?>/?text=<?= $mensaje; ?>">Enviar pedido a <?= $comercio; ?></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que tu problema no es de data, sino la accion de envío, te comento que tienes mal el header, te falta el location y le puse comillas dobles para trabajar las variables sin concatenacion.

aqui el codigo

```php
.....
   $arreglo = implode(",", $arreglo);
              #var_dump($arreglo);
              #ESPACIO PARA ENVIAR EL MENSAJE
                 $texto = "El usuario ".$nombre_usuario." ha solicitado los siguientes productos: ".$arreglo;
                 #$texto = utf8_decode($texto);
                 header("Location: https://wa.me/$num/?text=$texto");
```

Comment: Buen día,si pongo las variables sin concatenación no las reconoce, hace la redirección hacia whatsapp pero no muestra ni el número al que debe enviarse ni el mensaje @Alberto Marun

Comment: Estas usando comillas dobles para esta accion, cierto?

Comment: @JulioGuerrero En realidad comillas simples, las dobles fue una recomendación de Alberto Marun pero si se pongo las variables sin concatenar no funciona, yo lo tengo de forma que hace la redirección después de 5 segundos, así: `header('refresh:5;url=https://wa.me/'.$whatss.'/?text='.$texto);`

Comment: pero ya puedes enviar el mensaje si o no?, se resolvio o no el problema que tenias?